# Unable to Execute System function by Modifying EIP Register

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, buffer-overflow, shellcode, eip

I am currently practicing Buffer Overflows and Reverse Engineering. My code contains an unused function. My intention is to call the unused function by modifying EIP Register. But when i do that, The program starts a Process and quits.. The Function seems to be called but the txt file was not created as intended.

My Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int helper(){
    system("touch pwn.txt");
}

int overflow() {
    char buffer[500];
    int userinput;
    userinput = read(0, buffer, 700);
    printf("\nUser provided %d bytes. Buffer content is: %s\n", userinput, buffer);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    overflow();
    return 0;
}
```

I got the Address of the "helper" Function as below with gdb

[Address of helper Function (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/insIu.png)

I reversed it to send it into the buffer as shown..

[Reversed Text to call the helper function (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEYiJ.png)

When run, The Program starts a process and quits.. No txt file is created as intended.

[Program starts a process and exits (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR7a8.png)

How to i Fix it Guys?

Note:
I found the Offset to modify EIP register using pattern module in the peda tools.

[Pattern Tools in peda (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl4kk.png)

The EXE File was built as a 32 bit executable on a 64 bit OS using -m32 flag with gcc compiler.

```
OS : PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
     NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
     ID=kali
     VERSION="2020.2"
     VERSION_ID="2020.2"
     VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
     ID_LIKE=debian

GCC : gcc version 9.3.0 (Debian 9.3.0-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I got the Address of the "helper" Function as below with gdb

The address you got: `0x565561b9` indicates that you compiled a [position independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), which is loaded at a different address every time it runs (except under GDB, because GDB disables address randomization).

As a first step, you should rebuild your executable with `-fno-pie -no-pie` flags, and run it with ASLR disabled (just like it runs under GDB):

```
setarch `uname -m` -R /root/vulnerable
```

Once you get that working, you'll need to figure out how to make it work with ASLR enabled (ASLR is intended to make exactly this attack harder).